# Z3 Maximise and Conflicts

Tags: optimization, z3, maximization

I have the following Z3 problem. When the code here is executed, how shall we expect, or how is it defined, that the conflicting optimisation goals will perform?

```
(declare-const x Bool)
(declare-const y Bool)
(declare-const z Bool)
(maximize(
  +   
    (ite (= y false) 1 0) 
    (ite (= z false) 1 0)
  )
)
(maximize(
  +  
    (ite (= x true) 1 0) 
    (ite (= y true) 1 0) 
    (ite (= z true) 1 0)
  )
)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Currently, these are the results:

```
(+ (ite (= y false) 1 0) (ite (= z false) 1 0)) |-> 2
(+ (ite (= x true) 1 0) (ite (= y true) 1 0) (ite (= z true) 1 0)) |-> 1
sat
(model 
  (define-fun y () Bool
    false)
  (define-fun z () Bool
    false)
  (define-fun x () Bool
    true)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Z3 solves one optimization goal at a time. It commits one solution and uses the committed solution when solving the next goal. I call this "weak lexicographic" ordering because the committed solution can over-constrain the problem.
You can also configure Z3 to solve the objectives indepdendently or using pareto fronts.
The command-lines are:

```
(set-option :opt.priority pareto) ; find pareto fronts
(set-option :opt.priority lex)  ; weak lexicographic
(set-option :opt.priority box)  ; independent
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj, I also noticed the `(assert-soft...)` feature just now which also relates to this situation.